# Is IP for maps.googleapis.com keeps changing or Fixed

Tags: api, dynamic, ip, public

We have an Internal Server on which we want to use GEOCODING and accessing the URL from site `maps.googleapis.com`. Now we need Firewall Rules to allow the Internal Server to access `maps.googleapis.com` and have got 3 different IPs from different DNS Server which is OK.

Now if we get these Firewall Rules done, then can google change the IPs which resolve to `maps.googleapis.com` quite frequently.
Please advise.

Comment: Please advise if there is an IP Subnet which can be added to Firewall Safely and the New IPs will be from that Subnet Range.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular fixed IP address for any given Google site, I'm afraid, and as you've noticed they can change at any time. Your best bet is to look up the all the IP space that Google owns, and add those to your outbound firewall rules.

Here's a support article that might help:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The spf answer does not give you the list of IPs for maps.googleapis. This link apparently does https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/prelaunch-checklist#firewall. Configuring firewall with domain name is not a good idea because it only works for a limited period... I wrote a quick bash to nslookup and just add to list of known IPs. I then use zabbix to alert me when a new IP is found and add it to the iptables. You can also do this automatically but this is not something I chose to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check how many new IPs in this name?
#
# Usage: $0 <name> <ipfile>
#        <name>  : name to resolve
#        <ipfile>: file with IP addresses known for that name
#
# Example; $0 hello.google.com /usr/share/zabbix-agent/files/hello.google.com-iplist.txt

if [ $# -ne 2 ];  then echo "Error code 1 : wrong number of arguments" && exit 1; fi
if [ ! -f $2 ];   then echo "Error code 2 : file $2 does not exist" && exit 1; fi

name=$1
iplist=$2
dig="/usr/bin/dig"
lookup="/usr/bin/nslookup"

response=(`${lookup} ${name} | grep -i address | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e "1d"`)

if [ ${#response[@]} -lt 1 ]; then echo "Error code 3 : No Addresses returned by $lookup"  && exit 2; fi

for ip in "${response[@]}"
do
  if [ -z `grep ${ip} ${iplist}` ]; then
    echo "Error code 4 : Address ${ip} not found in $iplist" && exit 3
  fi
done

# All good.
echo "Return code 0 : All addresses for $name listed in $iplist"
exit 0
```

Hope that helps..